# RAM issues when accessing photos from Documents?

Tags: ios, swift, caching, offline-caching, offline-mode

Currently I am storing the photos like this

```
let imgData = self.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.2)

try imgData.write(to: Documents.directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("\(name).jpg"))
```

And i am accessing the photos like this:

```
let data = try? Data(contentsOf: Documents.directoryURL.appendingPathComponent("\(name).jpg"))

let image = UIImage(data: imgData)
```

`enum Documents` being this:

```
enum Documents {
    static var directoryURL: URL { return FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0] }
}
```

Due to offline mode I need to store some photos and then delete them once they are uploaded.

And everytime I load the photo from the disk the RAM increases.
If I load 100 - 200 photos, the app will crash due to memory issues. (it will go over 1GB)

I dont think the photos take up that much.

When I have them in RAM before storing them to disk (in an array) they dont take up a lot.

Its only **when they get loaded from disk** is when they bloat the RAM.

I switched to JPG from PNG so its a little bit better, but there must be something I am missing here or a rookie mistake I am making.

I am hoping **a black belt in iOS** out there might clear this up for me.

Also, what would be the best practice if you wanted to store large number of photos to documents, in case I am not doing it right ?

Comment: Have you benchmarked? What are the sizes of Data before and after the compression?